# Dry This Ruby Code

Tags: ruby, refactoring, dry

How can I DRY out this code?

```
module TraverseTree
  def inorder_traverse root
    return nil unless root
    result = []
    result.concat inorder_traverse root.left if root.left
    result.push root.val
    result.concat inorder_traverse root.right if root.right
    result
  end

  def preorder_traverse root
    return nil unless root
    result = []
    result.push root.val
    result.concat preorder_traverse root.left if root.left
    result.concat preorder_traverse root.right if root.right
    result
  end

  def postorder_traverse root
    return nil unless root
    result = []
    result.concat postorder_traverse root.left if root.left
    result.concat postorder_traverse root.right if root.right
    result.push root.val
    result
  end
end
```

Is there a good way to programmatically order the code based on function names?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def traverse_recurse(root, options)
  return unless root
  options[:preorder].call(root.val) if options[:preorder]
  traverse_recurse(root.left, options)
  options[:inorder].call(root.val) if options[:inorder]
  traverse_recurse(root.right, options)
  options[:postorder].call(root.val) if options[:postorder]
end

def traverse_collect(root, type)
  result = []
  traverse_recurse(root, type => lambda { |val| result.push(val) })
  result
end

def preorder_traverse(root)
  traverse_collect(root, :preorder)
end

def inorder_traverse(root)
  traverse_collect(root, :inorder)
end

def postorder_traverse(root)
  traverse_collect(root, :postorder)
end
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks a lot!
Just a quick follow-up questions, do you think this is worth doing though?
I mean the unDRYed and DRYed code are pretty much the same length, and the DRYed one seems more complex. In the realworld production, would you suggest doing so?

Comment: @marwei Yes, without a doubt. Repetitious code is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I think @marwei's concern is entirely valid. Their original code has some repetition, but its intent is very clear. Chris's code isn't bad per se, but it's *much* less obvious. @marwei's code is fairly self-documenting, but I would not commit Chris's `traverse_recurse` method to my repo without several lines of comments. Readability is just as important for maintainability as DRYness.

Answer (score 2):

As Chris' answer points out there are certainly ways to eliminate repetition here, but as I mentioned in my comment on their answer, I think your original code is very good in that its *intent* is very clear. Even without any comments I can tell right away what each method does, and I would hate to see you lose that.

However, I do see one way that you can get rid of some boilerplate without sacrificing readability.

Here's your first method:

```
def inorder_traverse root
    return nil unless root
    result = []
    result.concat inorder_traverse root.left if root.left
    result.push root.val
    result.concat inorder_traverse root.right if root.right
    result
  end
```

The first thing that jumps out at me is `result = []; ... (return) result`. This is often a code smell in Ruby, but it's not immediately obvious how to get rid of it, so I'll come back to it.

The second thing that jumps out is that this method checks if `root.left` is `nil` before calling`inorder_traverse` with `root.left` as an argument, which is good, but then `inorder_traverse` immediately checks if its argument is `nil`. We don't need to do that twice.

If we eliminate those postcondition checks, we end up with this:

```
def inorder_traverse(root)
  return unless root
  result = []
  result.concat(inorder_traverse(root.left))
  result.push(root.val)
  result.concat(inorder_traverse(root.right))
  result
end
```

**This isn't right**, however, because `Array#concat` will raise a TypeError when `inorder_traverse` returns `nil`. We can fix that problem by using `Array#push` with a splat (`*`):  When the argument is an array it works just like concat, and when the argument is `nil` it works just like concat with an empty array:

```
def inorder_traverse(root)
  return unless root
  result = []
  result.push(*inorder_traverse(root.left))
  result.push(root.val)
  result.push(*inorder_traverse(root.right))
  result
end
```

You may have already realized, though, that if we're splatting one argument to `push`, we can just splat all of the arguments in one `push` instead of calling `push` three times:

```
def inorder_traverse(root)
  return unless root
  result = []
  result.push(
    *inorder_traverse(root.left),
    root.val,
    *inorder_traverse(root.right)
  )
  result
end
```

...but hang on a second. If we're just initializing an empty array, pushing a bunch of elements onto it, and then returning it, why don't we just splat those elements directly onto the array when we initialize it?

And so:

```
module TraverseTree
  def inorder_traverse(root)
    return unless root
    [ *inorder_traverse(root.left),
      root.val,
      *inorder_traverse(root.right) ]
  end

  def preorder_traverse(root)
    return unless root
    [ root.val,
      *preorder_traverse(root.left),
      *preorder_traverse(root.right) ]
  end

  def postorder_traverse(root)
    return unless root
    [ *postorder_traverse(root.left),
      *postorder_traverse(root.right),
      root.val ]
  end
end
```

P.S. One more thing you could do is replace `return unless root` with `root && ...` (or `root and ...`). I find this very tempting but also a little smelly, so I leave it to you:

```
def inorder_traverse(root)
  root && [
    *inorder_traverse(root.left),
    root.val,
    *inorder_traverse(root.right)
  ]
end
```

### Bonus

I inevitably got to thinking about how one could really eliminate all repetition from the above and came up with the below code, which is hastily-written, untested, and entirely ill-advised. But it was fun to write!

```
module TraverseTree
  ORDERS = %i[preorder inorder postorder].each do |order|
    define_method(:"#{order}_traverse", 
      &method(:traverse_by).curry(order))
  end

  private
  def traverse_by(order, root)
    root && [
      traverse_by(order, root.left),
      traverse_by(order, root.right)
    ]
    .insert(ORDERS.index(order), root.val)
    .compact.flatten
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much for walking me through this, @Jordan! I like the splat idea a lot. It actually got me wondering how the performance differs between push and concat. You might have read this before but I'll just share it here [http://www.continuousthinking.com/2011/09/07/ruby_array_plus_vs_push.html](http://www.continuousthinking.com/2011/09/07/ruby_array_plus_vs_push.html)

Comment: And the && trick is really interesting to know, although I agree with you in that it makes the code a little less readable. Here's another naive question: in production, how would you rank the importance of readability, DRYness and performance?

Comment: That's a great article. I'm curious how `[].push(*foo)` compares to `[ *foo ]`; maybe I'll benchmark it the next time I'm at a computer.

Comment: Wrt your question, I don't know if they can be ranked, really. DRYness is important for maintainability. If you calculate a tax rate in four places in your app and have to change it, you're likely to miss it in one place, so it's better to move that repeated code into one method that's easy to test. Readability is important because being able to quickly and easily understand the code you're reading makes you less likely to introduce bugs when you make changes. DRYness and readability reduce bugs and save money in development.

Comment: Better performance can either save money, by saving time for the people who use the app (i.e. if the users are inside your company) or make money, by improving user experience/satisfaction/engagement and making them want to use your app. But not all performance optimizations have equal merit. In Ruby method calls are (relatively) expensive, so inlining code (which often isn't very DRY) can give performance benefits (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) but premature optimization (while [*not* the root of all evil](http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451)) is often a trap. It's good to write code with performance in mind, but if I'm saying to myself, "I could make a performance optimization here, but it would make it less readable/maintainable," in the absence of actual knowledge of the performance impact I'll choose readability/maintainability and not worry about performance unless and until I can identify actual issues in real-world use.

Comment: That's a great answer. There were a few times when I found myself un-DRYing some code for better performance. It feels like among readability, DRYness and performance, I can at best get two out of all three. What you said makes a lot of sense. Thank you @Jordan!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get really funky on this thing here is a functional way to do it.

```
left_vals = -> traverse_order, root { traverse_order[root.left] if root.left }
right_vals = -> traverse_order, root { traverse_order[root.right] if root.right }
current_val = -> traverse_order, root { root.val }
traverse = -> parts, traverse_order, root { parts.inject([]) { |array, part| array.concat(Array(part[traverse_order, root])) } }
inorder_traverse = traverse.curry.([left_vals, current_val, right_vals], -> root { inorder_traverse[root] })
preorder_traverse = traverse.curry.([current_val, left_vals, right_vals], -> root { preorder_traverse[root] })
postorder_traverse = traverse.curry.([left_vals, right_vals, current_val], -> root { postorder_traverse[root] })
```

then you can call;

```
postorder_traverse[root]
inorder_traverse.(root)
preorder_traverse.call(root)
```

They are all equivalent.

Comment: Was an interesting challenge to convert it. I actually find it quite readable aside from the density, I'm partly curious about the performance of different solutions as there is no state in the functional version. So you provided a good test case for me to look at. :)